# Can you seperate the Input in a Tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to make a programm with Tkinter where you type in some stuff (like Bananas,Apple,Watermelone) and then I want to put those things in a list. Can I somehow seperate the Input I get with the .get function?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

root = Tk()
Eingabe=Entry(root)
l = list()
eget=l.append(Eingabe.get)

def rNdm():

    x = randint(0, 3)
    for r in l:
        if l.index(r) == x:
            print(r)
            myLabel=Label(root, text=r)
            myLabel.pack()

Eingabe=Entry(root)
Eingabe.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Rndm", command=rNdm)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the code I have until now, but it only prints out stuff like that.
[This is the Tkinter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fSfx.png)

(And if you wonder why the code looks so unsorted, I'm only a beginner)

Comment: `Eingabe.get().split(",")`

Comment: you forgot `()` in `get()`. `get()` gives string so you can use `split(",")` to get list. You have do it in function `rNdm` which you run using button after adding text in `Entry.`. You can't do it after creating `Entry` because it doesn't work like `input()` - `Entry` doesn't wait for you text - `mainloop()` starts window - so you try to use `.get()` before you even see window.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: `import *` is not preferred. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This isn't a tkinter problem. The data is just a string. Python has many tools for doing string processing.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `()` in `get()`.

`get()` gives normal string so you can use `.split(",")` to convert string `"Bananas,Apple,Watermelone"` to list `["Bananas", "Apple", "Watermelone"]`

But you have other problem: `Entry()` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your text. It only informs `tkinter` what widget it has to display in window. And `mainloop()` starts everything. It displays window with widgets. So your code tries to get text from `Entry` before you can even see it on screen - so it can get only empty string. You have to run it in your function `rNdm` which you run using `Button`.

And the same is in most GUIs - not only in Python.

---

**BTW:**

To get random element from list you can use `random.choice(your_list)`

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random         # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def rNdm():
    global l  # inform function to use external variable when you will assign value (`=`) to this variable
    
    text = eingabe.get()
    l = text.split(",")
    random_item = random.choice(l)
    my_label['text'] = random_item  # replace text in existing `Label`

    print('l:', l)
    print('random_item:', random_item)
    
# --- main ---

l = list()   # it is global variable

root = tk.Tk()

eingabe = tk.Entry(root)  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
eingabe.pack()

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Rndm", command=rNdm)
my_button.pack()

my_label = tk.Label(root)  # without text
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which keep last 5 words on list and display these words in one `Label`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random         # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def rNdm():
    global all_words  # inform function to use external variable when you will assign value (`=`) to this variable
    
    text = eingabe.get()
    
    items = text.split(",")
    random_item = random.choice(items)
    
    all_words.append(random_item)
    all_words = all_words[-5:]   # keep only last 5 words
    
    my_label['text'] = "\n".join(all_words)  # replace text in existing `Label`

    print('items:', items)
    print('random_item:', random_item)
    print('all_words:', all_words)
    
# --- main ---

all_words = list()   # it is global variable

root = tk.Tk()

eingabe = tk.Entry(root)  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
eingabe.pack()
eingabe.insert('end', 'Bananas,Apple,Watermelone')

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Rndm", command=rNdm)
my_button.pack()

my_label = tk.Label(root)  # without text
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Version which use `Listbox`+`Scrollbar` to display all values.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random         # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def rNdm():
    global all_words  # inform function to use external variable when you will assign value (`=`) to this variable
    
    text = eingabe.get()
    
    items = text.split(",")
    random_item = random.choice(items)
    
    my_listbox.insert('end', random_item)
    
    all_words.append(random_item)
    
    print('items:', items)
    print('random_item:', random_item)
    print('all_words:', all_words)
    
# --- main ---

all_words = list()   # it is global variable

root = tk.Tk()

eingabe = tk.Entry(root)  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
eingabe.pack(fill='x')
eingabe.insert('end', 'Bananas,Apple,Watermelone')

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Rndm", command=rNdm)
my_button.pack()

# --- Listbox + Scrollbar (in Frame to organize it) ---

results = tk.Frame(root)
results.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

my_listbox = tk.Listbox(results)  # without text
my_listbox.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(results)  # without text
my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# connect scrollbar with listbox
my_scrollbar['command'] = my_listbox.yview
my_listbox['yscrollcommand'] = my_scrollbar.set

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explenation, but now I have another problem. When I use the button like 30 times my Monitor is full and I cant see anymore output. Do you know how I can delete a Output so the new one can be seen or better do you know how I can make a scrolabell "label" ?

Comment: see my version - I don't create new `Label` for new value but I create only one `Label` at start and later I replace text in this single `Label` - so I alwasys have only one value on screen. You can also get text from this `Label` append new line at the end and remove first line when there is too many values - and this way you can decide now many lines to display. It may be simpler if you will keep all values on list and get last 30 values from list to display in Label - ie. `list_values.append( random_item)` and `my_label['text'] =  "\n".join( list_values[-30:] )`

Comment: If you want scrolled widget then you may use `Listbox + Scrollbar` or `Text + Scrollbar` or `ScrolledText` because tkinter can't scroll `Frame with Labels`

Comment: I added example which uses list with last 5 values to display in one Label, and example which uses `Listbox + Scrollbar` to display all values. If you will have other problems then create new question on new page.